# Permutations with some fixed numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations, combinations

You have to fill 4 spaces with 3 numbers (4, 5, 6) such that the numbers 4 and 6 appear atleast once in every case. Find the number of such *unique* permutations. [Ans. 50]

How do you go about solving this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3^4=81$ ways to fill the spaces, ignoring the restriction.  Now we subtract the ways that don't have $4$, which is $2^4=16$, and the $16$ that don't have $6$, but we have subtracted twice those (only one) that have neither $4$ nor $6$.  $81-16-16+1=50$.  This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: can you elaborate the later part a little bit please for me